# How to drag one div below another using -ve margin, and make the dragged div beneath?

Tags: html, css

I have an html like;

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="diva"><br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva<br>diva</div>

</div>
<div class="divb">divb</div>
```

`wrapper` and `divb` divs are having 100% width, and `wrapper` contains a child div, which holds some text. The child div `diva` don't have a fixed height, and is designed to stretch according to text. I want `diva` to stretch 50px into `divb` also, and I added a -ve margin of 50px to divb. But divb is hiding diva, and I want diva visible. Below is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The pink div is hidden by blue div. I want pink div to be visible. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/hT63N/) is the live demo. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to .diva:

```
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hT63N/1/)